# Identifying services hold by svchost.exe

Tags: operating-systems, process

How can we identify which services are running on a particular svchost.exe. Are those services dependent on each other or are they just wrapped up with particular svchost.exe ?

Answer (score 1):

There are at least 2 methods known to me of identifying the services under a certain `svchost.exe process`:

1. Use command-line parameters

Your can simply enter

```
tasklist /svc /fi "IMAGENAME eq svchost.exe
```

which gives an output similar to this:

```
Image Name                     PID Services
========================= ======== ============================================
svchost.exe                    964 BrokerInfrastructure, DcomLaunch, LSM,
                                   PlugPlay, Power, SystemEventsBroker
svchost.exe                    364 RpcEptMapper, RpcSs
svchost.exe                   1064 Appinfo, Browser, DoSvc, LanmanServer,
                                   lfsvc, ProfSvc, RasMan, Schedule, seclogon,
                                   SENS, SessionEnv, SharedAccess,
                                   ShellHWDetection, Themes, UserManager,
                                   Winmgmt, WpnService
svchost.exe                   1072 CryptSvc, Dnscache, LanmanWorkstation,
                                   NlaSvc, TapiSrv, TermService
svchost.exe                   1220 AudioEndpointBuilder,
                                   DeviceAssociationService, hidserv,
                                   NcbService, Netman, PcaSvc, SensorService,
                                   StorSvc, SysMain, TabletInputService,
                                   TrkWks, UmRdpService, WdiSystemHost, wudfsv
```

you can then have a better idea on whats running under a particular `svchost.exe`, in addition I believe these svchost processes are not entirely dependant on one another but rather tied to each process.

2. Svchost.exe look-up tool (third party tool)

   - Alternatively you could go for a freeware third-party tool [svchost.exe Lookup](http://www.tweaking.com/content/page/tweaking_com_svchost_exe_lookup_tool.html) Tool from Tweaking.com which serves a similar process:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

its doable yes. the scvhost itself can run one more multiple windows DLLs and usually nothing to care about for a normal user - however Process Explorer helps you to identify the stuff behind the scvhost.

https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/download/process-explorer/

Bleeping computer has made a pretty nice overview of that stuff and you might wanna take a look at it with your spare time ;)

https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/tutorials/list-services-running-under-svchostexe-process/